# Ifelse in datatable not working when R shift() type is lag

Tags: r, datatable

I have a dataframe like this :

```
   timestamp           Status
05-01-2020  12:07:08    0
05-01-2020  12:36:05    1
05-01-2020  23:45:02    0
05-01-2020  13:44:33    1
06-01-2020  01:07:08    1
06-01-2020  10:23:05    1
06-01-2020  12:11:08    1
06-01-2020  22:06:12    1
07-01-2020  00:01:05    0
07-01-2020  02:17:09    1
07-01-2020  12:36:05    1
07-01-2020  12:07:08    1
07-01-2020  12:36:05    1
07-01-2020  12:36:05    0
08-01-2020  12:36:05    1
08-01-2020  12:36:05    0
08-01-2020  12:36:05    0
09-01-2020  12:36:05    1
09-01-2020  12:07:08    0
09-01-2020  12:36:05    1
11-01-2020  12:07:08    0
11-01-2020  12:36:05    1
```

The first condition in ifelse is not working. Is it because of me trying to use `lag` in `shift` function? Here is my code.

```
 df[, difference := ifelse((df$Status == 0 & shift(df$Status,type='lag') == 1) & (as.Date(df$timestamp) !=  shift(as.Date(df$timestamp),type = 'lag')),
    as.numeric(df$timestamp - as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(timestamp)," ","00:00:00"),tz="UTC"),units='mins'),ifelse((df$Status == 1 & shift(df$Status,type='lead') == 0) & as.Date(df$timestamp) !=  shift(as.Date(df$timestamp),type = 'lead'),as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(timestamp)," ","23:59:59"),tz="UTC") - df$timestamp,units='mins'),
    as.numeric(shift(df$timestamp,type = 'lead') -  df$timestamp,units='mins')))]
```

Comment: Yes ... Other conditions are working well!

Comment: The `as.Date` seems to be wrong  YOu may need `as.Date(timestamp, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")` assuming it is month-day-Year

Comment: I have some conditions... Status 1 means my start and 0 means end... I need to find duration between 1 and 0. But if 1 and 0 are occuring on same day its a straight forwad substaction.  If 1 is on first day and 0 on second day then there should be a split happening at 12 midnight.. we may have multiple occurrences of 1 and 0. Also 1 and 0 appear in any order.But we calculate between 1 and 0.. At the end I will be doing a daywise sum of duration.

Comment: The timestamp is already converted in that format before doing this... As I told you the second  ifelse onwards it is working fine..but when i have a lag in shift it is not working

Comment: Ohh my example data was created using excel.. i guess the format got changed... Yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss is the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could first consider to create the 'date' column by specifying the correct `format`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date := as.IDate(timestamp, "%m-%d-%Y")]
df[, timestamp := as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")]
```

then, create the `ifelse` or `fifelse`, make sure the `NA` from `shift` is changed by making use of `fill`

```
df[, i1 := Status == 0 & shift(Status, fill = first(Status)) == 1]
df[, i2 := date != shift(date, fill = first(date))]
df[, i3 := Status == 0 & shift(Status, fill = last(Status), type = 'lead') == 0]
df[, i4 := date != shift(date, fill = last(date), type = 'lead')]
```

and then use the `fifelse/ifelse`

```
df[, difference := fifelse(i1 &i2, 
      as.numeric(difftime(timestamp, as.POSIXct(date), units = 'mins')),
        fifelse(i3 & i4, 
       as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(paste(date, "23:59:59"),tz="UTC"),
       timestamp, units = 'mins')), as.numeric(difftime(shift(timestamp, 
        type = 'lead', fill = last(timestamp)), timestamp, units = 'mins')))) ]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = c("05-01-2020  12:07:08", "05-01-2020  12:36:05", 
 "05-01-2020  23:45:02", "05-01-2020  13:44:33", "06-01-2020  01:07:08", 
 "06-01-2020  10:23:05", "06-01-2020  12:11:08", "06-01-2020  22:06:12", 
 "07-01-2020  00:01:05", "07-01-2020  02:17:09", "07-01-2020  12:36:05", 
 "07-01-2020  12:07:08", "07-01-2020  12:36:05", "07-01-2020  12:36:05", 
 "08-01-2020  12:36:05", "08-01-2020  12:36:05", "08-01-2020  12:36:05", 
 "09-01-2020  12:36:05", "09-01-2020  12:07:08", "09-01-2020  12:36:05", 
 "11-01-2020  12:07:08", "11-01-2020  12:36:05"), Status = c(0L, 
 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -22L))
```

Comment: What is fill=first(date)?

Comment: Can you just help me to understand how it becomes NA?

Comment: Also where should i put my duration calculation?

Comment: It is not splitting. No condition is working for me. But it finds the difference without splitting.

Comment: @VictorJohnzon not clear about your comment.  what splitting you want